# android getString to int

Tags: android, spinner

I'm getting data from web service, this data show on spinner object and works fine ... so when I selected one ítem of Spinner I can't convert the value "ultima_jornada" (its String value) to Integer ... could you help me please?

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),item,
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      JSONObject json_obj;
    try {
        json_obj = ljsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        String lsJornada = json_obj.getString("ultima_jornada");
        int jornada = Integer.parseInt(lsJornada);
        jornada = jornada;
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The data of Web Service

```
{"Datos":[{"id_torneo":"9","tor_nombre":"10:00 P.M","ultima_jornada":"0"},{"id_torneo":"11","tor_nombre":"7:00 PM","ultima_jornada":"15"},{"id_torneo":"7","tor_nombre":"8:00 PM","ultima_jornada":"4"},{"id_torneo":"8","tor_nombre":"9:00 PM","ultima_jornada":"2"},{"id_torneo":"5","tor_nombre":"Atardecer Ant.","ultima_jornada":"17"},{"id_torneo":"3","tor_nombre":"De los Desvelados","ultima_jornada":"16"},{"id_torneo":"12","tor_nombre":"Dominical Femenil","ultima_jornada":"0"},{"id_torneo":"13","tor_nombre":"Dominical Varonil","ultima_jornada":"0"},{"id_torneo":"10","tor_nombre":"Juvenil Sabatino","ultima_jornada":"0"},{"id_torneo":"6","tor_nombre":"Sabatino Libre","ultima_jornada":"8"}],"status":0,"mensaje":""}
```

Comment: We will need to see the underlying JSON data to help

Comment: Or just show us the stack trace that is printed in logcat.

Comment: change `e1.printStackTrace();` to `Log.e("SomeTagIdString", e1.getMessage(), e1);`

Comment: Since you're not checking if the value CAN be parsed, you could just use json_obj.getInt. Without seeing the JSON there isn't much we can do, though...

Comment: Erstwhile .... I put the data

Comment: petey  never enters the exception

Comment: What exactly do you want to do on this line `jornada = jornada` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without errolog it is hard to define what is throwing the exception, but I think this line is wrong: 
*Integer.parseInt* it should be *Integer.valueOf* therefore the exception is not thrown because you are just throwing a Json-exception... 
If my hint does not work change your exchange to the base class **Exception** thereby all errors will be thrown in the catch statement